# What is the correct way to query two columns in a table using AND OR in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two columns in my products table, category1, and category2.  In my categories table I have four different categories, if a product falls under that category, the category number comes under the category1 column, if it comes under another category at the same time, that category is entered into the category2 column, a product does not come under more than two category types simultaneously.

Here is an example:

```
productID | category1 | category2
1         | 1         |
2         | 1         | 2
3         | 2         |
```

So category type 1 will always be in the category1 column, and if the same product comes under category type 1 and 2 as shown above in product id 2, then this causes me problems when querying all products that are of category type 2.

Here is my first query where I want to retrieve all the products which come under category type 1:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category1 = 1
```

My second query where I want to retrieve all the products which come under category type 2:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category1 = 2 AND OR category2 = 2
```

I know the second query is wrong, I just wrote it as I need it to work.

I cannot figure out how to query two columns with one query, only by writing two separate queries, any suggestions is appreciated. I am using SQL Server 2008 so special SQL functions may not be supported.

Comment: I don't understand. Aren't you just trying to do `SELECT * FROM products WHERE category1 = 2 OR category2 = 2`?

Comment: which product ID's do you expect to get from query 2 (using your example)?

Comment: I tried that solution, this just runs the first part of the query and only returns the first part, it never returns the second part after the OR doing it this way.

Thanks.

Comment: What is "category type 1": `category1` or `categoryX` that has value 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category1 = 2 OR category2 = 2
```

This will select all rows that have value 2 in one (or both) of the columns. Furthermore you can use it for any value (changing the value, of course) including value 1. This makes it easy to create a prepared statement in your client software (if you have one) that uses just one variable.

Comment: Thanks, I made a silly mistake with my pagination code that was limiting my pages, I could't see further into the query and didn't notice, all this time I thought the query was wrong I was doing it correctly. Thanks for the answer it made me realise the error was somewhere else in my code!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the following is what you want:

```
Select
    *
From 
    Products
Where
    Category1 = 2 or
    Category2 = 2
```

However I think you may want to reconsider your table design. Whenever I see multiple simliar columns labels with numeric suffixes, I consider it a design smell.

An alternative is to create a seperate ProductCategories table with 2 columns: ProductID and Category. Your PK would be a compound key of both. If you used this design, the SQL you'd need to find all category 2 product would be:

```
Select
    Products.*
From 
    Products
Inner Join
    ProductCategories
On
    Products.ProductID = ProductCategories.ProductID
Where
    ProductCategories.Category = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will bear this in mind for the future!

Thanks!